# Can a Function on a Closed Disc be Extended to a Larger One?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I'm really stuck on this problem!  Given: a closed disc $D$ and a continuous function from the solid cylinder $f: D \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that's a homeomorphism at each $t \in [0,1]$.   So $f_t = f|_{D \times \lbrace t \rbrace}$ is a homeomorphism with its image for every $t$.

Problem: Extend this to a function on $\mathbb{R}^2 \times I$ that's a homeomorphism at each $t$, but $|f_t(x) - x| \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

I know you can extend each $f_t$ like that, but not how to do it for a cylinder.

Comment: How do you extend each $f_t?$

Comment: It's given to us.  It's a long proof using the Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: Very confusing wording. When you say $f_t$ is a homeomorphism, you mean to say it’s a homeomorphism *to,its image*?

Comment: Sorry yes.  I'll fix it.

Comment: https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00719540/document  Here is a proof of the first question asked.  The statement is Corollary 2.11